# jQuery Delegation Issue

Tags: jquery, delegation, raty

I am using the Raty Rating plug-in for jQuery in a webpage as seen below in, my issue is that when I add a comment with my code I can't get the rating as the rating code is generated on the fly by the jQuery code, I assume this is a delegation issue but unsure where to put my comment form submission code to allow it to get the rating value!?

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="comment">
    <div>
        <p>Your comment: </p>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Generates the Raty Rating code below
            $(".rating").raty({
                hints: ['Poor', 'Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent'],
                path: "media/images/",
                size: 24
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div class="rating"></div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="104" name="tid" id="tid">
    <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Code generated by raty rating:

```
<div class="rating" style="cursor: pointer; width: 140px;">
    <img src="media/images/star-off.png" alt="1" title="Poor">&nbsp;
    <img src="media/images/star-off.png" alt="2" title="Fair">&nbsp;
    <img src="media/images/star-off.png" alt="3" title="Good">&nbsp;
    <img src="media/images/star-off.png" alt="4" title="Very Good">&nbsp;
    <img src="media/images/star-off.png" alt="5" title="Excellent">
    <input type="hidden" name="score">
</div>
```

script.js

```
$("#comment").on("click", "button", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var tid = $('#comment #tid').val();
    var rating = $('#comment #score').val();
    var comment = $('#comment #message').val();

    alert(tid+"\n"+rating+"\n"+comment);

});
```

Made it clear as to what the code is doing at present.

Comment: You'll have to call `.raty` where your code is getting generated.

Comment: Delegation is only useful for binding event handlers, not initializing widgets.

Comment: @Barmar, would it not be delegation as the score element is generated on the fly so the code in script.js will never see the score element?

Comment: Delegation applies to _events_. This isn't an event, it's a widget initialization.

Comment: @Barmar, I get you now, thanks.

Comment: @Barmar, the click on the button in #comment is an event though?! Which is the problem, I'm trying to get the score element from the raty code once the button is clicked?

Comment: Widgets are more than just event handlers. It needs to do stuff when it's initialized, like add the stars to the DOM, and then it adds its own event handlers. But the real point is that the handler bindings are done by the widget itself, not by you -- the widget would have to provide its own API for delegation.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the explanation, I figured it out, I used the native function from raty to populate a hidden element that already exists on the page and can access the value now, thanks again.